# Send Email and Attachment

Tags: winrt-xaml

I used below code to send email.  But when I run it in Simulator in VS, the email client can not be launched. What I did wrong? But the Email Client launched in Localmachine mode.

```
var mailto = new Uri("mailto:?to=recipient@example.com&subject=Win8 Email&body=n Hi.");

await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(mailto);
```

Comment: Which's your default email client ?

Comment: I just created an Win8 App and added a button in the MainPage to call the code above ad Bebug in Simulator mode. In the Simulator I saw my Live mail acct when clicked the windows button to launch the start screen. Where is this default email client? Please help. Thanks

Comment: I mean to say if you run that code in local machine than which mail client is being open. Win 8 Mail app ? Outlook ? Any other ?

Comment: For me working fine with my Outlook.

Comment: For testing in LocalMachine, it launched the Web Email ( Not Outlook). When testing in Simulator, it shows Email ICON same as the one in localMachine testing BUT it WONT go further to show To and Subject and content in body.

Comment: What do you mean by "Web Email" ? In Browser ?

Comment: I don't know how to call it. It did not launch OUTLook Mail. If you press the Windows Button in Win8, the Mail Client with Mail-Icon is the one that launched BUT freeze in Simulator. What suppose to launch if you use above code and test in simulator? Thanks

Comment: Ok, you mean the default "Metro" mail app right. `mailto` opens the mail client which is set as default mail client. You can set `mailto` protocol from control panel -> default programs.

Comment: I did the setting in the Win8 Emulator control panel-> Default programs. Selected Mail and set mailto protocol. When tested, result was the same - showed up the background with envelop icon but did not go further to show TO, Subject and Body. Do I need to test this in REAL device??

Comment: Yes. might be problem with simulator.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer.

Using WinRT in Windows 8.0 you cannot attach an attachment at this time.

Sorry if that is not the answer you wanted to hear.

You can always use a service to send the email; then you can/could do anything.

Comment: When I tested the above code in LocalMachine Mode, it launched the mail client showing TO, Subject and content for Body. When I right clicked on the anywhere, it showed up a bar at the bottom which include a Attach icon. This means I can send attachment right?

Comment: Yes, but you cannot automate it. The user has to do it.

Comment: You can do this in Windows 8.1

Comment: Will look into this. Thanks for this valuable feature.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT I can't find how to do it in Windows 8.1, adding the `&attachment=C:\file.png` at the end of the URI does not work (even with the file access rights). Is there something I am missing?