# WinRT Send Email With Attachment

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

This issue is related to the one

[Send Email and Attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460113/send-email-and-attachment)

I want to know that In Windows 8.1, how to add parameter of email attachment in the same URI

var mailto = new Uri("mailto:" + mailFrom + "?subject="+mailSubject+");

In this statement, we have set subject parameter, but how do we set an attachment parameter.

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need to use Uri (+ LaunchUri I assume) or can you instead use the share interface? I.e. you could maybe use this method (sharing files..): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh871371.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it in Windows 8.1 I believe. I would use a web service that handles email for you. I think Windows 10 might have some APIs to handle it:

[`Windows.ApplicationModel.Email namespace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.email.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Filip for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
use EmailMessage class for this.This class is available only in windows phone 8.1 and above.it is not supported for winrt 8 and 8.1. A sample code can look like this:

private async void SendBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage { Subject = "Sending test file" };
    email.To.Add(new EmailRecipient("myMailbox@mail.com"));

    // Create a sample file to send
    StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("testFile.txt", Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    await FileIO.WriteTextAsync(file, "Something inside a file");

    email.Attachments.Add(new EmailAttachment(file.Name, file)); // add attachment
    await EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(email); // send email
}
```